# Determine nearest element with a z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a proper way of determining if an element (any element) closest to the targetted element has a z-index?

For example, I append a div to a layer of DOM and I want to know if there's an element near that div with a z-index so i can position that div accordingly so it won't get lost under the layers because I don't know where and when it would be appended.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have a hint plugin that appends hints to a page dynamically and then saves them on a server. I'd post the code but i'm afraid it won't be of much relevance to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I would crate a function like the below one. It traverses through each of the element's parents and checks if it has a z-index

```
    function getElement($target){
       var $parents = $target.parents();
       for(var i=0;i<$parents.length;i++){
          if($parents[i].css('z-index').length>0){
              return $parents[i];
          }
       }
       return false;

    }
```

Comment: Good idea, although I sense it might be rather slow since there will be a lot of traversals going on at the same time for all the hints that are appended. I'm gonna may be limit the parents() to a fixed number of levels and try that out. Thanks.

Comment: @nainy the parents() method will return an array with the first member being the closest parent.. So the above answer will check from the closest element to the farthest.. so i think its not going to result in too many traversals but minimum number of traversals required to get the answer. It might be a good idea to get array of elements of the specific type that you want to check against, if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

My is a similar solution as the one from Sethunath.

```
/**
 * Helper to retrieve the z-index which is required to bring up the dragged element in front.
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
getZIndex: function () {
    if (this.z_index === undefined) {

        var recrusive_z_index_search = function(element) {

            // Break on body.
            if (element[0] === $('body')[0]) {
                return 2;
            }

            // Get parent element
            var parent = $(element).parent();

            // Check if parent has z-index
            var z_index = parent.css('z-index');
            if (z_index.length > 0 && !(/\D/).test(z_index)) {

                // Return found z-index.
                return z_index;
            }

            // Z-index not found, try again on next parent.
            return recrusive_z_index_search(parent);
        };

        this.z_index = recrusive_z_index_search($(this.element));

    }
    return this.z_index;
},
```

This solution was added within an object class. this.element is the starting point from where it searchs. It stops when we found an element with z-index not really a one with a numeric value, because z-index can also be set to "auto". If we reached the body we break the chain and set it to 2 by default as a fallback.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Firefox firebug` https://getfirebug.com/ or `Chrome Developer Tools` (built in Chrome) to `inspect the element` you'd like to find the z-index of.

Appending the element near another `div` isn't related to the z-index property. The `z-index` will bring the highest number element in front when objects overlap. Otherwise, it is not the property you are looking for. Especially if you didn't define any `z-index` properties for other elements.

CSS specificity is what you might be looking for [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question, might be my fault. I need to make sure that the div I append is going to be (at least more or less) on the same level with the other elements on the page. The only way I can do that is to somehow determine the closest possible z-index on that particular layer where the div was appended and then steal it for that div. It all happens dynamically.

Comment: Why can't you append the element with a high z-index? ex, 1000. That way it will always be in front.

Comment: That way It can be either be too high (which means all the hints will pop on top of the layers they shouldn't be on) or too low (lots of layers, modals and popups with high z-indexes).

Comment: I just need to comment on those answers from MCSharp with "why you can't just use ...." We, the developer, mostly know exactly what we want and what not, if we ask for a specific problem, we really need this specific case. Sometimes it can happen that a simple way is better, but not often... To the question, I think really you have to traverse back with parent() in a recrusive method call till you reach body.